# Bash: Capture exit code instead of aborting, when "set -e" is set?

Tags: bash

For the most part, I prefer my scripts to terminate when encountering an unexpected error, and thus usually start them with `set -e -u -E -o pipefail`.

However, sometimes I need to capture the exit code of a single call and *not* terminate. This leads to constructs like

```
# (1) Verbose. Breaks when moved between scripts 
#              with different global -e setting.
set +e
COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES
exitCode=$?
set -e

# (2) Verbose.
if COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES
then exitCode=$?
else exitCode=$?
fi

# (3)
exitCode=0
COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES \
    || exitCode=$?

# (4) Brittle, must not mix up order of && and ||
COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES \
     && exitCode=$? || exitCode=$?

# (5), doesn't work with `set -o pipefail`
COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES | cat
exitCode=$PIPESTATUS

# (6) Requires maintaining a function across scripts.
captureExitCode COMMAND WITH A LOT OF ARGUMENTS \
    | AND MAYBE EVEN PIPES \
    | MAYBE OVER MANY LINES
# where
captureExitCode() {
    # any of the above constructs with "$@" as command
}
```

All of these are either verbose or somewhat hard to parse visually, especially if `COMMAND ...` is a multiline piping command. At least, they don't communicate their intent well. In the case of `captureExitCode` the function has to be reproduced across scripts.

Is there some less verbose builtin idiom for capturing the exit code?

Answer (score 0):

Run the problematic commands in a sub-shell and disable `errexit`:

```
(
  set +e
  run buggy code failing without proper error handling
)
exitcode=$?
```

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

if ( set +e
     false
   )
then
  echo success
else
  echo failure
fi
```

Btw: when you write the pipe this way, you do not need the backquote:

```
echo abc |
  tr a x |
  sed 's/^x/y/'
```

Comment: Disabling "fail on error" isn't the issue. The problem lies in doing so, capturing the exit code for processing, and avoiding verbose constructs at the same time.